# Mysql return Max(id) for multiple tables along with one value from one specific table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new with mysql and I need some help.

I have 10 tables in my database.

On of them is named as "hibernate" and schema is like this

[image]

Column "entity" contains names of other tables in database.

What I need is query which will return me one row for each table, with 3 column:

1. table name
2. max(id) of the table
3. the value of the next_hi column in hibernate table for the table

Like this:

[image]

It would be great if it could do for each "hibernate" table and pick up TableName from "entity" column and get MaxId for that TableName and return row like picture above with "next_hi" also

EDIT:

If it's not possible to get this by reading Table names from "hibernate" table
it will also help if I can get this working with Table names hardoced in Query.

I have example which I made for one table "Account":

```
SELECT  
hibernate.entity as TableName, 
hibernate.next_hi, 
MAX(Account.Id) as MaxId

From Account 

INNER JOIN hibernate
    ON "Account"=hibernate.entity;
```

But now I don't know how to modify this query to return this for multiple tables.

Comment: The question is "Why ?" I think... ; this sound like something you shouldn't have to do...

Comment: To be honest, I don't know why :) One of the my tasks on work is to build this query. It will be used for something but I don't know for what

Comment: not the best way to work... ; whenever, remove the `sql-server` tag of your post and add a `sql` one please

Answer (score 2):

Best way for me is with trigger :

```
  -- change end of line DELIMITER
DELIMITER //

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trg_account_last_id`;
//

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_account_last_id`
AFTER INSERT ON `Account`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  UPDATE `hibernate`
  SET `hibernate`.`last_id` = NEW.`id`
  WHERE `hibernate`.`entity` = 'Account';

END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

On every table you put this simple trigger that update a `last_id` field on your `hibernate` table.

With this a simple `select * from hibernate` will give you what you want...

---

But this is not really optimized. It work. After it depend when you need this data. maybe an hard coded version is better...

If you want to go with the hard-coded :

```
(
  SELECT
    `hibernate`.`entity` as `TableName`,
    `hibernate`.`next_hi`,
    (SELECT MAX(`Id`) FROM `Account`) as `MaxId`
  FROM `hibernate`
  WHERE `hibernate`.`entity` = "Account"
)
UNION ALL (
  SELECT
    `hibernate`.`entity` as `TableName`,
    `hibernate`.`next_hi`,
    (SELECT MAX(`Id`) FROM `Page`) as `MaxId`
  FROM `hibernate`
  WHERE `hibernate`.`entity` = "Page"
)
UNION ALL (
  SELECT
    `hibernate`.`entity` as `TableName`,
    `hibernate`.`next_hi`,
    (SELECT MAX(`Id`) FROM `User`) as `MaxId`
  FROM `hibernate`
  WHERE `hibernate`.`entity` = "User"
)
-- and again for other tables
```

Comment: Well hard coded version would be better for me. If you can help mi with writing script which will do the job for multiple tables.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Sorry but I have to ask is there any way to loop through all tables in database and do this, because if my database have 20 tables this is going to be really big script.

Comment: @carpics do you need a SQL only answer ? a bit of PHP or Shell may help a lot as MySql is awful with this kind of things. other question, how many time this command will be used ? it's a heavy one, and should not be run lightly...

Comment: Yes I need SQL, I would know how to resolve it with a bit of PHP. Regarding how many times the command will be used, well I am not really sure because I am not going to use it

Comment: @carpics not easy in full sql; maybe with a stored procedure. I'll take I look if I found something